# Error in !is_num : invalid argument type - what does this mean in the context of attempting to do linear regression with interaction term?

Tags: r

I keep getting this error when I attempt to run my code which should give me linear regression with an interaction term - all of my other regressions with this data run fine so I don't know why this one is giving me an error and i have no idea what this error means?

```
reg4 = lm(time ~ cases * distance)
library(olsrr)

Attaching package: ‘olsrr’
The following object is masked from ‘package:datasets’:

rivers
ols_regress(reg4)
```

> Error in !is_num : invalid argument type

Comment: What line of code are you running that is causing this error?  The way your question is written, it looks like `library(olsrr)` is returning the error `ols_regress(reg4)...` which just can't be...

Comment: May I also ask why you have tagged your question with the SO tags `sql`, `xml`, `function`, and `numeric`?  None of those seem to apply here.

Comment: I cannot run the first line of your code.  Please check it.  What is the definition of `reg4`?